# How to configure a Kubernetes Multi-Pod Deployment

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I would like to deploy an application cluster by managing my deployment via k8s Deployment object. The documentation has me extremely confused. My basic layout has the following components that scale independently:

1. API server
2. UI server
3. Redis cache
4. Timer/Scheduled task server

Technically, all 4 above belong in separate pods that are scaled independently.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to create `pod.yml` files and then somehow reference them in `deployment.yml` file or can a deployment file also embed pod definitions?
2. K8s documentation seems to imply that the `spec` portion of `Deployment` is equivalent to defining *one* pod. Is that correct? What if I want to declaratively describe multi-pod deployments? Do I do need multiple deployment.yml files?

Comment: From my understanding, you cannot have different Pods in the same deployment. I was wondering how I could add 2 different Pods (1 container each) to the same Deployment. I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Pagid's answer has most of the basics. You should create 4 `Deployment`s for your scenario. Each deployment will create a `ReplicaSet` that schedules and supervises the collection of `Pod`s for the `Deployment`.

Each `Deployment` will most likely also require a `Service` in front of it for access. I usually create a single yaml file that has a `Deployment` and the corresponding `Service` in it. Here is an example for an `nginx.yaml` that I use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: nginx
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32756
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginxdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginxcontainer
        image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Here some additional information for clarification:

- A `Pod` is not a scalable unit. A `Deployment` that schedules pods is.
- A `Deployment` is meant to represent a single group of pods fulfilling a single purpose together.
- You can have many `Deployments` work together in the virtual network of the cluster.
- For accessing a `Deployment` that may consist of many `Pod`s running on different nodes you have to create a Service.
- Deployments are meant to contain stateless services. If you need to store a state you need to create `StatefulSet` instead (e.g. for a database service).

Comment: Thanks Oswin. Your syntax example combining `Deployment` and `Service` in one is extremely helpful!

Comment: i'm confused about the use of `port: 80` and also `nodePort: 32756` in the same service. Can you please explain why they are both needed?

Comment: The `port: 80` says that if you address the service as an entity, e.g. through the DNS entry for its name or the service IP, the port 80 will forward to the PODS supplying the actual service. `nodePort: 32xxx` says that if you address the cluster nodes, e.g. from the outside via a loadbalancer or node IP, the port 32xxx will forward to the PODS supplying the actual service.

Comment: I thought the point of a deployment was to monitor a group of pods? I don't understand why I need to create a deployment for each pod.

Comment: How do you ensure multiple deployments/services get deployed together & come online together, and should one fail, that the other deployments don't deploy?

Comment: @fionbio: Check out Readiness Probes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes

Comment: @OswinNoetzelmann Thanks - I've taken this to mean that having multiple deployments in a file, or running apply against a directory of files, does not mean the whole operation is treated atomically, and some deployments may succeed and others may fail. True?

Comment: @fionbio: Yes, you can influence what constitutes success with defining probes and there is no boundary on what you can come up with. You are free to create indirect dependencies between deployments and so on. So you should carefully design a solution for your domain that makes sense and is easy to use/upgrade. Complicated designs are easy - Simple is hard.

Comment: How do you connect the different deployments together? For instance if I have 2 deployments, one for node and one for postgres, how do I let node know how to connect to postgres? In docker-compose the name becomes the dns hostname, but I don't understand how that's accomplished across deployments.

Comment: @Fmstrat : Typically service DNS is used. Please refer to the following link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: @OswinNoetzelmann Is there an example yaml that shows this working with Deployments instead of pods?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the Kubernetes [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/) for the [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#deployment-v1beta1-apps) and you'll find that the `spec`->`template` field is of type [`PodTemplateSpec`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#podtemplatespec-v1-core) along with the related comment (*Template describes the pods that will be created.*) it answers you questions. A longer description can of course be found in the [Deployment user guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

To answer your questions...

1) The `Pods` are managed by the `Deployment` and defining them separately doesn't make sense as they are created on demand by the Deployment. Keep in mind that there might be more replicas of the same pod type.

2) For each of the applications in your list, you'd have to define one `Deployment` - which also makes sense when it comes to difference replica counts and application rollouts.

3) *you haven't asked that but it's related* - along with separate `Deployments` each of your applications will also need a dedicated [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) so the others can access it.

Comment: Thanks @pagid. To be clear, while `spec` -> `template` is indeed a `PodTemplateSpec`, it is still the spec for a *single* pod. Is that right?

Comment: Also, regarding #1, I am sensing there are two options: 1) inline pod spec or 2) external reference via labels. For my initial project, for the sake of my sanity I'll stick to inline pod spec.

Comment: We'll a deployment can have a `replica` definition - therefore the `PodTemplateSpec` accounts for a group of Pods and the `replica` config, defines how big that group is.
The external definition is something which I'm not able to "see" as an option when using the API definition along.

Comment: "it is still the spec for a single pod. Is that right?" YES, a single pod template spec that might cause multiple pods to be instantiated.

Comment: do you recommend having seperate service for seperate deployments? I guess using same service and having different ports would be easy to maintain as there are small number of services right? This is just my assumption, please let me know if you have different thoughts on this.

Comment: One Service for multiple Deployments is the way which is nowadays used most often.

Answer (score 1):

additional information:
API server                    use   deployment
UI server                     use   deployment
Redis cache                   use   statefulset
Timer/Scheduled task server   maybe use a statefulset (If your service has some state in)